# How to return values in alphabetical sort and combine Uppercase and lowercase strings - php

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php

//Get any text from input
$text = $_POST['text'];

//Regex for cleaning unwanted symbols
$regex = "/[a-zA-Z']+/";

//Split text to single words
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $words);

?>

<?php foreach ($words as $array): ?>
    <?php $my_array_values = array_count_values($array); ?> 
        <?php while (list ($key, $val) = each ($my_array_values)): ?>
            <div class="single_word">
                <?php echo $key; ?>
                <span class="word-count"><?php echo $val; ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Code returns value and count:**

- Lorem 1
- ipsu'm 1
- dolor 3
- sit 1
- lorem 5
- nullam 1

  now I want to sort in alphabetical, but combine Lorem and lorem

Comment: use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert array into string

Comment: I don't know what `array_icount_values` is, but if you want to count a single word you can use `array_count_values($array)[$word]`, but better save the array in the outer loop or use a custom count function yourself.

Comment: That function you posted first does not make any sense at all, I doubt that is something you found on php.net... `$ret_array` is explicitly assigned an empty array, iterating over it in the inner loop makes zero sense.

Comment: Can you show us what `$words` looks like?

Comment: that function does exist on php.net - according to the author "I couldn't find a function for counting the values with case-insensitive matching so I wrote a quick and dirty solution" - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: I edited my code, and please refresh page to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Map values of the array of words to their respective lowercase values. Make an array of word and their count of appearance using `array_count_values` function.

Sort this resulting array in place using its keys by applying the `ksort` function.

**Side Note**: Taking advantage that arguments to functions are passed by value. This allows for better composition. We can be sure that our original array is left unmodified and a new one that is sorted returned.

```
function lexicalKeySort($arr) {
    ksort($arr);
    return $arr;
}

$words = ['lorem', 'Lorem', 'dolor', 'ipsum'];
$wordCount = array_count_values(
                array_map('strtolower', $words)
            );


var_dump(lexicalKeySort($wordCount));
```